# Converting "Windows Form" project to "Windows Form (.NET Framework)" project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

**Context**:

Visual Studio 10, Win 10, developping an Winform application in VB.Net

**Issue**:

I can't add a webview control to my forms and lots of other controls are grayed out

**Cause**:

Following the answer of sribasu [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58964214/vs2019-some-toolbox-components-greyed-out/67963350#67963350), it seems that this issue found its origin in the fact that my app was a "Windows Form App" instead of "Windows Form App (.NET platform)" (sorry, i use VS 2019 in French, not sure about the translation

**Question**:

Is there a way to convert my project to be able to use controls like Webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found something on [Microsoft forums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/511952/how-do-i-convert-a-c-windows-forms-app-project-to.html).

To change the project type, edit the vbproj file of the project, find the line with TargetFramework and edit it like this:

```
<TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
```

There could be some things that won't compile though. -_-

Comment: And to complete: to add a webview control in .NET 5.0 winform project, just add SDK WebView2. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms

Comment: Done. Sorry for the delay, i'm still a stackoverflow rookie considering the rules...